# Is it possible to get mouse events from a Spark Line or Path object in Flex 4?

Tags: apache-flex, flex4

I'm drawing an arrow as a `<s:Path>` and I need to get notified when the mouse is over it. How can I do that?

The arrow is an element of a Group container.

I tried registering for MOUSE_OVER events for both the container and the arrow and none seem to fire...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Path](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/primitives/Path.html?filter_flex=4.1&filter_flashplayer=10.1&filter_air=2) doesn't extend [InteractiveObject](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/primitives/Path.html?filter_flex=4.1&filter_flashplayer=10.1&filter_air=2) and therefore does not allow fur mouse interaction.  Your best bet is to wrap up your path inside another component that can extend InteractiveObject, such as a [Sprite](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Sprite.html).

You can make your own  "ClickablePath" class.

Comment: So you're saying I should inherit from Sprite and add the Path as an element of Sprite? But I don't think Path can be added as an element to Sprite...

Comment: Yes, that was my suggestion.  I chose Sprite because it is a common element in Flash for drawing stuff.  If Path can't be added on a Sprite, then what are you currently adding it to?  You could do UIComponent, but I thought that Sprite might be higher up in the chain and slightly more effecient.

Comment: I don't think I can addElement to UIComponent, either. Right now I'm inheriting from Path.. maybe I should try Group as a base class? Although I suspect I might get on-over events fired for the bounding box instead of the arrow within.

Comment: Yup, inheriting from Group fires events according to the bounding box.

Comment: Correct, addElement is only in components that extend SkinnableComponent, or groups.  When extending UIComponent you would use addChild. Essentially they are the same thing, just different.

Comment: I ended up extending SkinnableContainer and the mouse events are trigged for the path alone.

Answer (score 1):

Try encapsulating in a Graphic object (Flex4). See there: 
http://blog.flexexamples.com/2010/03/22/creating-a-simple-image-map-in-flex-4/